# Matlab clibgen - no "enum" property in generated library

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a problem trying to integrate C++ code with MATLAB. I will show a simple example to illustrate my problem.
I have a header file `example.h` with the following code:

```
typedef struct
{
    enum
    {
        VALUE_1,
        VALUE_2,
        VALUE_3
    } example_enum;
    int example_val;
} Example;
```

I built my code and generated static .lib library. Now I am trying to compile and build this code in MATLAB with `clibgen`:

```
clibgen.generateLibraryDefinition('../src/example.h', "Libraries", '../LIB/libexample.lib', "PackageName", 'EXAMP')
```

When I call summary of `defineEXAMP` I see following:

```
>> summary(defineEXAMP)
MATLAB Interface to EXAMP Library
Class clib.EXAMP.Example
  Constructors:
    clib.EXAMP.Example()
    clib.EXAMP.Example(clib.EXAMP.Example)
  No Methods defined
  Properties:
    int32 example_val
```

In the "Properites" field I can only see the `int32` property, no enum. The same problem I have with a union data type, I don't see it in MATLAB.

Is it possible to compile this code in MATLAB to see this enum as property of `EXAMP`?

Comment: Interesting! Maybe it’s because an enum doesn’t map nicely to a MATLAB data type? There’s an enum in MATLAB, but it’s not very functional and it requires lots of boilerplate code. Unions don’t exist at all. Note that this way of linking libraries is meant to give access to external functions, my guess is that they haven’t put much effort into mapping every possible C (let alone C++) construct.